# Is it possible to create swap space in Ubuntu when it is upgrading from 14.04 lts to 16.04 lts?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, swap, ubuntu-16.04

In my current Office PC running on Ubuntu 14.04 lts without any swap partition(At the time of installation swap space was not created by installer). Now I want to create a swap space partition. I know there is a procedure to create swap file or swap partition.
visit https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq.
I need swap partition(as performance is better than swap file(swap file is as fast as swap partition when underlying file system for swap file is contiguously allocated) unless swap file will not get contiguous memory blocks). I know there is a procedure to create swap partition by again inserting bootable USB. Unfortunately I don't have any access to any USB port, so I want to know is it possible by upgrading to 16.04 lts from 14.04 lts so that if I will get an option to create swap space as I am thinking about to upgrade my system to 16.04 lts soon.

Comment: Sure. As long as you have an unused partition, (or free space to make a small partition out of), you can set the filesystem type to `Linux Swap`, format the swap filesystem `mkswap /dev/whatever`, and then `swapon` to activate it. Then just add an entry in `/etc/fstab` to it will automatically be enabled on boot.

Comment: David C. Rankin- will that swap file be allocated continuously on filesystem?.. And what if I upgrade my system to 16.04 Lts? Will I get an option to create swap space?, as I am thinking about to upgrade my system.

Comment: It works like this. Let's say you have 1G of free (unpartitioned) space on a drive. You create a partition with (`parted/gparted`, `fdisk`, `cfdisk`, whatever). You set the partition *type* to `0x82` (**Linux Swap**). Now you have a fresh new `1G` partition to use as your swap space. You now use `mkswap /dev/sdX` (where `X` is the device number created by partitioning). You now have a new partition with a swap filesystem on it that you can activate with `swapon`. (you add the entry to `/etc/fstab` so it is activated on boot). When you upgrade, it should use your existing swap.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, thanks for informative replay...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you selected the "Use LVM" option when you installed Ubuntu in the first place, you should be able to resize your partition using the [system-config-lvm](http://www.howtogeek.com/211937/how-to-use-lvm-on-ubuntu-for-easy-partition-resizing-and-snapshots/) utility. Otherwise, it will be extremely hard to do (if not impossible) if you can't boot from a USB device or CD. In this case, a swap file might be your only option.

Comment: What difference does it make if you use LVM or not? You can't shrink ext partition online. Also can do it without usb, just from initrd before mounting real root fs or something like https://github.com/marcan/takeover.sh